# Crystal Report DateTime field shows one day less than it should

Tags: .net, datetime, crystal-reports, timezone, dataset

I have an issue with Crystal Reports DateTime filed.It displays one day less than it should on the report when it is hosted on an Australian server (OS: Windows Server 2003 R2). But if it is resided locally (in Sri Lanka) (OS: Win 7) it works fine as expected.

The relevant DataSet returns the correct dates but with the time part ex : 
"11/08/2013 12:00 A.M" and in this case it would display "10AUG2013" if the report is on Australian server and "11AUG2013" if it is hosted in Sri Lanka.

I did try with having formula fields and formatting them to ignore the time part ex : CDate(), ToText() ,..etc but yet it considers -1 date on Australian server for some unknown reason :)

One workaround would be getting the formatted string with the DataSet but I would like to find out the root cause for this issue and try to resolve it.

I hope I have explained the issue clearly and hope to get some light on this.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially ShiftDateTime function with crystal reports did the trick for me until I found some issues with UK environment because they are close to GMT. later on I did further investigations on this and Emanuelle was right this is due to dataset issue.
The root cause for the issue was , it was adding a time offset on serializing the dataset. by default dataset datetime field has a DateTimeMode as "UnspecifiedLocal" which creates the offset. I just had to change it to "Unspecified" to avoid it being serialized with the offset.

ex:

```
foreach DataTable dtbl in dataset.Tables)

            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtbl.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
                    {
                        col.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
                    }
                }
            }`
```

(reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datasetdatetime(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Crystal Report problem; it is a Dataset problem.

[Remoted DateTime values in a DataSet object are converted to the equivalent local time of a remote computer that is in a different time zone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842545/en-us)

The article explains well, that you can face this problem if the time zone where data are stored and where they are used are not the same.

You can try many workarounds (ie remove time part and add 1 day for each date) but the best solution is tu set the same time zone for both servers (time zone don't have to be the place where the server IS but where USERS are supposed to be!)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `ShiftDatetime` function.

```
// shift from India Standard Time (IST) to Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST)
// IST doesn't have a daylight time; omitted
// daylight time support added for AEST
ShiftDateTime({table.date_time}, "IST,330", "AEDT,600,AEDT,60")
```

Comment: Thx craig, I was able to figure out a solution with your tip ShiftDateTime({Table.DepartureDate},"UTC,0", "") solved my issue. ref : http://taf-tech.blogspot.com/2008/04/automatically-adjusting-datetime-in.html